# Maxheap giving wrong result

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, heap, max-heap

I wrote the following code to build a maxheap from a already existing array the downadjust function makes the array a max heap but it is not producing results as desired
Please check the code and tell me where am I going wrong also it would be very helpful if someone suggest what changes to the downadjust function will help me in making a min heap ( that is the next question that I have to code)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void downadjust(int heap[],int i){
    // n is size
    int n=heap[0];
    int j,flag=1;
    while(2*i<=n && flag==1){
        j=2*i;
        if(j+1<=n && heap[j+1]>heap[j]){
            j=j+1;
        }
        if(heap[i]>heap[j]) flag=0;
        else
        {
            swap(heap[i],heap[j]);
            i=j;
        }
    }
}

void disp(int heap[],int n){
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        cout<<heap[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"no of stud";
    cin>>n;
    n++;
    int heap[n];
    heap[0]=n-1;
    
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        cin>>heap[i];
    }
   
    for(int i=n/2;i>=1;i--){
        downadjust(heap,i);
    }
    
    disp(heap,n);
    
    cout<<endl;
    
    cout<<"max is "<<heap[1];

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no of stud => implies No of Students as in my problem I am supposed to take marks of n number of students

Comment: `cin>>n; n++;int heap[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are achieved by using `std::vector<int> heap(n);`

Comment: in heap[0] i am storing the number of students i.e number of entries in the array
I am not using 0'th location of array for storing any data only size is stored in that I hope this clear your doubt

Comment: `std::make_heap(heap.begin() + 1, heap.end());` -- That is a one line solution. See [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap).

Comment: can anyone just tell me with the same code what changes would give me the expected result

Comment: Why do you think that program is wrong? `6 1 3 9 4 2 5 7` gives valid heap `9 7 5 6 4 2 3 1`

Comment: Paul that's so nice of you for suggesting a one linear solution but we are not allowed( at college level) to use inbult func. or stl we are asked to write the core logic as we are still in our initial stages of learning

Comment: @Athrav_N *but we are not allowed* -- But you are allowed to use invalid, non-standard C++??  So how are you going to create the dynamic array?  The only other option is to use `new[]/delete[]`.

Comment: MBo for the input (9 size )
   5 1  9 2 11 50 6 100 7 its giving wrong result

Comment: @Athrav_N [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).  Second, just for fun, compare your output with what `std::make_heap` produces.  Is it the same?  If it is, what's the issue?  You should use whatever it takes to verify what you have actually works, and utilizing `std::make_heap` gives you assurance as to whether your home-made code actually works or not.

Comment: result `100 11 50 7 5 9 6 2 1` is valid heap

Comment: I am trying to say for the input 5,1,9,2,11,50,6,100,7
the output should have been 100 50 11 7 2 9 6 1 5 but its not producing that

Comment: No, it shouldn't! You cannot expect left-right ordering of children

Comment: Got that MBo thanks for that
, Also thanks Paul for the idea,
can you guys help me make minor changes in same code to create a min heaap

Comment: @Athrav_N -- *for the input 5,1,9,2,11,50,6,100,7 the output should have been 100 50 11 7 2 9 6 1 5* -- It's time to verify your expectations using `std::make_heap`.  [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/zGjsocMf7)

Comment: Thanks for that Paul and I got that now just a fun fact I thought my result is wrong because the book I was referring to had the wrong solution to the problem so I was thinking my program is wrong ☺️

Comment: Can you guys help me with the last thing of making changes to create min heap using same code

Comment: @Athrav_N -- You have to make the attempt.  One hint is that if you look at `std::make_heap`, to get a min-heap, all that is required is to set the comparison to do a "greater than" instead of "less than".  See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zosPdffvq).  So make that similar change to the code you have now.

Comment: @Athrav_N The book might have a different code that results in a different heap. For any input there are many solutions that are correct heaps.

Comment: @Athrav_N -- In addition, by using `std::make_heap` as a checking tool, you have something to prove your output is correct if your teacher concludes that your output is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result for `5 1 9 2 11 50 6 100 7` is valid heap `100 11 50 7 5 9 6 2 1`.

Perhaps you wanted `50 11` sequence and other ordered pairs of child nodes, but heap construction does not provide strict mutual ordering of children (as binary search tree does).

To make minheap, you just need to change two comparisons:

```
 if (j + 1 <= n && heap[j + 1] < heap[j]) {
        j = j + 1;
    }
    if (heap[i] < heap[j]) flag = 0;
```